# How to send transactional email based on the shipping method selected in magento2

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping, email, shipping-methods

I have installed collect in store module shipping method. When the order is placed a order confirmation is sent to customers which is magento default transnational email.

Can we send separate email when the shipping method selected as collect in store?

Comment: is that in magento1 or magento2 ?

Comment: hi, it is in magento2.

Comment: Hi, have you got the solution ? Looking for same

Comment: @AjwadTaqvi, yes i have resolved it myself

Comment: Can you please post it in answer so that I can get help.

Comment: Or share Github link or any other usefulls ?

Answer (score 0):

I have override Email Order Sender, to do so

add this in your Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

```
<preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender" 
     type="Vendor\Module\Model\Email\Sender\OrderSender" />
```

Then in OrderSender.php

```
 <?php
 namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Email\Sender;
 use Magento\Sales\Model\Order;

 class OrderSender extends 
 \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender
  {
 protected function prepareTemplate(Order $order)
 {
   parent::prepareTemplate($order);


    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart');
    $quote = $cart->getQuote();         
    $shippingMethod = $order->getShippingMethod();      
    $objectManager->get('Psr\Log\LoggerInterface')->info($shippingMethod);                  

    if($shippingMethod == 'pickupatstore_pickupatstore_1'){  //your shipping method
      $templateId = 12; //your templateId
    }else{
        $templateId = $this->identityContainer->getTemplateId();
    }

    $this->templateContainer->setTemplateId($templateId);
  }

 }
```

Hope this will help you!!!

Comment: hi @Ajwad, is it worked for you?